# Very small BEAM pCollection did not get flushed to output files

Tags: apache-beam, avro, dataflow

I have a pCollection that contains Avro records and I used AvroIO to write to output files. All working fine till recently I found when the collection was super small like 20 records or so, the output does not show up. I think what happened would be some buffer not been flushed. I think the FileIO or AvroIO should have a flush function. How can I force the flush?

Here is the sink part of the pipeline

```
myPCollection.apply(FileIO.<String, GenericRecord>writeDynamic()
            .by(new OutputGroupFun())
            .via(AvroIO.sink(eventSchema))
            .withNaming(new FileNameFn(myOption.getOutputGcsDir()))
            .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
            .withTempDirectory(myOption.getAvroTempDir())
            .withNumShards(1));
```

Comment: I isolated those input files with single digit record counts that were read among other bigger files. Ran the same dataflow template with only these small input files. Output generated as expected. However, blended with other bigger files, output wasn't there.

Comment: Is this a batch or streaming pipeline?

Comment: (BTW, all records *should* be flushed, pending the watermark advancing.